# Invisible pictures in system applications

Tags: macos, ios, services

While just browsing through apps like the CoreServices in both Mac and iOS, I found that most (all?) of the pictures have sizes and memory, but don't show anything when I quick look or open them. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images stored in CoreServices, such as those in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`, should be easily viewable in Finder — though, the majority of these are in the `icns` format. I'm also able to view the `png` images inside `Dock.app`. (Which particular images can't you view?)

[image]

But most `png` images on iOS are **optimized for display on iOS** (which involves switching some color channels and otherwise reducing the file size), so you can't view them in OS X without some preprocessing. See [this blog post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html) for more information.

Comment: Right now, what I was looking at was SpringBoard. I'll try copying them to the Pictures folder so I can view them on the iPhone. Thanks!

Comment: There are tools such as [iPhonePNGApp](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/29611/iphonepngapp) which can convert the files for you, as well.